# Launching a .sh file at startup with variables

Tags: command-line, bash, startup

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get

```
sudo ./razer_blackwidow_chroma_driver/scripts/driver/set_static.sh 255 60 0
```

to execute at startup. I've tried adding it to both `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, as well as adding it to the Startup Applications Preferences, but nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the script isn't running? It could be executed and then failing due to some error.

Comment: Try running it in a terminal. Does it throw an error and fail?

Comment: Neither `sudo` nor a relative path (`./something`) are things that belong in rc.local - try it without `sudo` and with the full, absolute, path to the script. And `sudo` within your Startup Applications probably won't work either (it needs a tty and a password).

Comment: @biggles5107
It executes fine in a terminal. No errors and the keyboard illuminates as expected.

Comment: @steeldriver
How would I format the command with the full path? [/home/user/razer_blackwidow_chroma_driver/scripts/driver/setstatic.sh 255 60 0]?

Comment: @Nick yes that sounds about right - if you created the razer_blackwidow_chroma_driver directory right at the top level of your home dir

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easy way to execute your script after each reboot, you can use root crontab...

Just do (as root):

```
crontab -e
```

add this line:

```
@reboot /full/path/to/your/script param1 param2 ... paramN
```

save and test :)

To get the full path of your script just open a terminal, go to the script folder and execute

```
pwd
```

this will return you the full path for your current position.